# Robot framework: How to set the Excel file name and Sheet name at run time or as variable?

Tags: robotframework

```
Library     DataDriver      ../TestData/DataDriven/TestData_DataDriven.xlsx     sheet_name=ForgetUserID
```

I want to pass an Excel file's name and sheet name from Properties/config file. Is it possible to do in RF?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: The question is not clear. Kindly explain in detail.

Comment: Have you tried using a variable name for the filename?